# Suggestion Required: php application architecture

Tags: php, web-applications, architecture

My web application(http://www.tyro.in) lets users share their Documents like Ms word and pdf openly. Users can search and download the documents uploaded by other users. Currently app use the following technique

When user uploads any file:

It extracts text from document and stores in database. 
It stores file name as title of that DB record.

When user search for a file:

It matches the query with the stored data present in the Database and shows the results for download

current implemented technique in graphically given at http://www.tyro.in/Tyro.png

Any one suggest me the advancement of my current method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suggestions for searching info:

1. use full text search in the name and description fields
2. categorize the documents (by file type, user, info, size)
3. add info about popular searchs and most downloaded documents
4. let users rank documents so they can be easily found
5. let users share documents (via email, social networks)

if i have more ideas, i'll let you know

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

But I never had time to try.

Comment: this answer might interest you then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338889/3339034#3339034

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a short preview of file upon search,
to avoid unnecessary downloads - will gain both users and your bandwidth.

regards,
/t