# MySQL CREATE FUNCTION Syntax

Tags: sql, mysql, database, function, mysql-function

I am trying to create a function in MySQL:

Here is the SQL code:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION F_Dist3D (x1 decimal, y1 decimal) 
RETURNS decimal
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE dist decimal;
  SET dist = SQRT(x1 - y1);
  RETURN dist;
END;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10
```

I am running this create statement in phpMyAdmin. What is wrong with this function?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You have to override your `;` delimiter with something like `$$` to avoid this kind of error.

After your function definition, you can set the delimiter back to `;`.

This should work:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION F_Dist3D (x1 decimal, y1 decimal) 
RETURNS decimal
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE dist decimal;
  SET dist = SQRT(x1 - y1);
  RETURN dist;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That did it.  I thought using phpMyAdmin would eliminate the delimiter hack.  Thanks!

Comment: example
    `DELIMITER $$`
    `CREATE PROCEDURE mysql_user_count()`
    `BEGIN`
        `SELECT 'Mysql user table' description, COUNT(*) record_count FROM mysql.user;`
    `END$$`
    `DELIMITER ;`

Comment: Yeah cause PHPMyAdmin is so great. I would suggest using HeidiSQL if you are going to be working with functions / procedures.

Comment: Could somebody explain why wrapping the function/procedure in a different delimiter makes this work? I don't understand the underlying problem.

Answer (score 27):

**MySQL create function syntax:**

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION GETFULLNAME(fname CHAR(250),lname CHAR(250))
    RETURNS CHAR(250)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE fullname CHAR(250);
        SET fullname=CONCAT(fname,' ',lname);
        RETURN fullname;
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Use This Function In Your Query

```
SELECT a.*,GETFULLNAME(a.fname,a.lname) FROM namedbtbl as a


SELECT GETFULLNAME("Biswarup","Adhikari") as myname;
```

Watch this Video how to create mysql function and how to use in your query

[Create Mysql Function Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cURM2jgsGI)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6740975/6243352), for the sake of completeness, here's how to drop and call the function, along with a simplification to remove the intermediate variable (although OP probably has more work to do in the function and is just trying to get the syntax working):

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS F_Dist3D;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION F_Dist3D (x1 decimal, y1 decimal) 
RETURNS decimal
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  RETURN SQRT(x1 - y1);
END$$
DELIMITER ;

SELECT F_Dist3D(11, 2); -- => 3
```

Note that the assumption here is that `x1` is greater than `y1`, since `SQRT` expects a positive number.

Answer (score 0):

#### A [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html):

- can have zero or more SQL statements with [BEGIN ... END statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/begin-end.html). *No statement without `BEGIN ... END` statement gets error.
- can have only single [RETURN statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/return.html#:%7E:text=The%20RETURN%20statement%20terminates%20execution,procedures%2C%20triggers%2C%20or%20events.) not changing the delimiter to `$$` without error.
- can get zero or more values with zero or more parameters from the caller then, return a value to the caller.
- must return a value with [RETURN statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/return.html#:%7E:text=The%20RETURN%20statement%20terminates%20execution,procedures%2C%20triggers%2C%20or%20events.).
- must be `DETERMINISTIC` or `NOT DETERMINISTIC`. *If any one of them is not set, `NOT DETERMINISTIC` is set implicitly.
- can have [SELECT INTO statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) but cannot have `SELECT` without `INTO` otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880306/why-mysql-is-giving-error-not-allowed-to-return-a-result-set-from-a-function/77561561#77561561).
- can have [local variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/local-variable-scope.html) and [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference/77675418#77675418) explains local variables and user-defined variables.
- cannot have [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969875/error-code-1422-explicit-or-implicit-commit-is-not-allowed-in-stored-function/77676469#77676469).
- is atomic by default so if there is error, it is rollbacked automatically. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51092508/are-procedures-atomic-in-mysql/77668730#77668730) explains it in detail.

*[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) explains a function in detail.

For example, you create `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num int
);
```

Then, you insert the row whose `num` is `2` as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (2);
```

Now, you can create `addition(value INT)` function which adds `value` to `num` and returns `value` to the caller as shown below. *Without `DETERMINISTIC` gets [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015160/deterministic-no-sql-or-reads-sql-data-in-its-declaration-and-binary-logging-i/77533481#77533481) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946553/deterministic-function-in-mysql/77538553#77538553) explains `DETERMINISTIC` and you must set [RETURN statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/return.html) and `RETURNS <type>` clause to a function otherwise you get [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452085/no-return-found-in-function-error-in-mysql/77539334#77539334) and [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61518259/mysql-error-1064-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax/77540268#77540268) respectively and in a function, `SELECT INTO` is allowed to use but `SELECT` without `INTO` is not allowed to use because there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880306/why-mysql-is-giving-error-not-allowed-to-return-a-result-set-from-a-function/77561561#77561561) basically, you need to change the default delimiter `;` to something like `$$` when creating a function otherwise there is error, then after creating a function, you need to change the delimiter `$$` back to `;` as shown below and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql/77440483#77440483) explains delimiter and you must select a database when creating a function otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve/77491814#77491814):

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION addition(value INT) RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
UPDATE test SET num = num + value;
SELECT num INTO value FROM test;
RETURN value;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you can call `addition(3)` with [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) statement, then `5` is returned and `3` is added to `num` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT addition(3);
+-------------+
| addition(3) |
+-------------+
|           5 |
+-------------+
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|  5   |
+------+
```

In addition, you can create `addition()` function with the user-defined variable e.g. `@my_value` and without parameters as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION addition() RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN                       -- ↓ Here
UPDATE test SET num = num + @my_value;
SELECT num INTO @my_value FROM test;
RETURN NULL;    -- ↑ Here
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you set `@my_value` with `3` and call `addition()`, then `3` is added to `num` and `@my_value` has `num` value `5` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SET @my_value = 3;
...
mysql> SELECT addition();
+------------+
| addition() |
+------------+
|       NULL |
+------------+
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|  5   |
+------+
...
mysql> SELECT @my_value;   
+-----------+
| @my_value |
+-----------+
|         5 |
+-----------+
```

And, in this case below, you can create `addition(value INT)` function not changing the delimiter to `$$` without error:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION addition(value INT) RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
RETURN value;
```