# Mysql workbench creating a function

Tags: mysql, function

this is my code, pretty simple, I always get errors i dont know where I went wrong, please help:

create function fun1() returns int(1)
begin

return 1;

end ;
[image]

```
#   Time    Action  Message Duration / Fetch
```

0   1   11:20:30    end Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 1 0.000 sec

Answer (score 2):

Hi Can you please try below code with changing the delimiter:

```
    delimiter $$
    create function fun1() returns int(1) 

    begin

    return 1;

    end$$

    delimiter ;
```

Hope it will work for you.

MySql use `;` as default delimiter so delimiters other than the default  `;` are typically used when defining functions, stored procedures, and triggers wherein you must define multiple statements. You define a different delimiter like `$$` which is used to define the end of the entire procedure, but inside it, individual statements are each terminated by `;`. That way, when the code is run in the mysql client, the client can tell where the entire procedure ends and execute it as a unit rather than executing the individual statements inside.

[image]

Comment: As I have added screenshot, it works perfectly for me.
@KEVINBOSS  Can you share screenshot, what error are you getting?

Comment: Hi I have posted the screenshot can you see it?

Comment: @KEVINBOSS 
Can you execute following statement and try once :


SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;

for more details you can visit below link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015160/deterministic-no-sql-or-reads-sql-data-in-its-declaration-and-binary-logging-i