# I am getting Error Code: 1418 and I can't figure out how to clear the error

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble figuring out how to clear this error.  Any help would be appreciated.
Ray

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION discount_price
(item_id_param  varchar(10))
RETURNS DECIMAL(10, 2)
BEGIN
  DECLARE discount_price_var DECIMAL(10, 2);
    
  SELECT item_price - discount_amount
  INTO   discount_price_var
  FROM   order_items
  WHERE  item_id = item_id_param;
    
  RETURN discount_price_var;
END//
```

Comment: I see no error here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cpStHNG9UStav37GzBH1ua/0 . Please post full code and full error

Comment: Here is the full error I am getting.

14:21:40 CREATE FUNCTION discount_price (item_id_param varchar(10)) RETURNS DECIMAL(10, 2) BEGIN   DECLARE discount_price_var DECIMAL(10, 2);        SELECT item_price - discount_amount   INTO   discount_price_var   FROM   order_items   WHERE  item_id = item_id_param;        RETURN discount_price_var; END Error Code: 1418. This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable) 0.000 sec

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015160/deterministic-no-sql-or-reads-sql-data-in-its-declaration-and-binary-logging-i) To others that cross this question, know that error is with MySQL 8. The first comment's link is set to v5.7, and does not error with this version.

Comment: Thanks Paul! That was driving mad and what you sent solved my problem.