# Why MySQL is giving error "Not allowed to return a result set from a function"?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sql-function, mysql-function

I am trying to create a MySQL function using *phpMyAdmin* and getting this error.

> #1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a function

The function code is as below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
        
CREATE FUNCTION get_binary_count(a INT, c INT)
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC 
    
BEGIN
    DECLARE c1, c2 INT;
    SET c1 = 0;
    SET c2 = 0;
    
    SELECT left_id  AS c1 FROM mlm_user_mst WHERE parent_id = a AND left_id > 0;
    SELECT right_id AS c2 FROM mlm_user_mst WHERE parent_id = a AND right_id > 0;
    
    IF (c1 > 0 AND c2 > 0) THEN
        SET c = c + 1;
        SET c = c + get_binary_count(c1, 0);
        SET c = c + get_binary_count(c2, 0);
    END IF;
    
    RETURN c;
END$$
     
DELIMITER ;
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Already solve in stackoverflow, please visit link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177267/mysql-function-error-code-1415-not-allowed-to-return-a-result-set-from-a-func

Answer (score 43):

Because

```
SELECT left_id AS c1 FROM mlm_user_mst WHERE parent_id=a AND left_id>0;
```

doesn't set the variable c1, it returns a set with a column named c1

You want

```
SELECT left_id INTO c1 FROM mlm_user_mst WHERE parent_id=a AND left_id>0;
```

Similarly for c2.

Answer (score 8):

that is because you are using `SELECT` queries whose output is not stored into variables or temporary inside `FUNCTION` which must. Function can return only one single value. So your code should be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS SELECT left_id AS c1 FROM mlm_user_mst WHERE parent_id=a AND left_id>0;
CREATE TABLE t2 AS SELECT right_id AS c2 FROM mlm_user_mst WHERE parent_id=a AND right_id>0;
```

or

```
SELECT left_id AS c1 INTO @c1 FROM mlm_user_mst WHERE parent_id=a AND left_id>0 LIMIT 1; 

SELECT right_id AS c2 INTO @c2 FROM mlm_user_mst WHERE parent_id=a AND right_id>0 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In [a function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) and [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html), [SELECT INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) is allowed to use but `SELECT` without `INTO` is not allowed to use because there are the errors below. *In [a procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) and [event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html), `SELECT` without `INTO` is allowed to use:

> ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a function

> ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger