# What is the error in the following My Sql Code?

Tags: mysql, database

It always gives the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddRKV.png)

> #1415 : Not allowed to return a result set from a function.

pickup_request is a table; schedule_time is datetime variable and customer_id is the primary key and varchar(45) variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the output of all your SELECT queries into variables using  `INTO` + name of variable. In your example `SELECT schedule_time INTO @schedule_time`

Check also the answers to [Why mysql is giving error "Not allowed to return a result set from a function"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880306/why-mysql-is-giving-error-not-allowed-to-return-a-result-set-from-a-function)