# MySQL before insert trigger using select to check records in other tables - Getting ERROR 1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

```sql
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER tr_checkdata_bi
    BEFORE INSERT ON timesheets
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF  (NEW.EmployeeId NOT IN (
        SELECT EmployeeId
        FROM Employees
        WHERE NEW.EmployeeId = EmployeeId)) THEN
        CALL p_invalid_employeeid;
    END IF;

    IF (NEW.CustomerId NOT IN (
        SELECT CustomerId
        FROM Customers
        WHERE New.CustomerId = CustomerId)) THEN
        CALL p_invalid_customerid;
    END IF;

    IF (NEW.JobCode NOT IN (
        SELECT JobCode
        FROM JobCodes
        WHERE New.JobCode = JobCode)) THEN
        CALL p_invalid_jobcode;
    END IF;

END;

//

delimiter ;
```

I am fairly new to MySQL and when inserting a record into timesheets with an invalid `EmployeeId`, `CustomerId` and `JobCode`, getting ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger. How do I check for invalid records and report an error?

I was inserting a new record into timesheets with invalid data so that the code in the before insert trigger would be executed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why MySQL is giving error "Not allowed to return a result set from a function"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880306/why-mysql-is-giving-error-not-allowed-to-return-a-result-set-from-a-function)

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do with triggers what is supposed to be done with [foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: Your `p_invalid_jobcode` procedure tries to perform SELECT..

Comment: This is a documented restriction https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-trigger-restrictions