# No RETURN found in FUNCTION ... error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, return, mysql-function, mysql-error

I have browsed around and other solutions don't seem to be working for me here. I keep getting a 'No return found for function' error when trying to create this function in MySQL. Any idea why?

```
CREATE FUNCTION `mydb`.`myfunction`(Name varchar(20))
RETURNS int
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
SELECT SUM(Transaction.Bought) INTO @Qty FROM Transaction WHERE Transaction.Name = Name;
RETURN @Qty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `myfunction`(`Name` VARCHAR(20) CHARSET utf8) RETURNS INT NOT DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
MAIN: BEGIN
DECLARE returnVal int;
SELECT SUM(`Transaction`.Bought) INTO returnVal FROM `Transaction` WHERE `Transaction`.Name = Name;
RETURN returnVal;
END MAIN;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Jake how are you invoking the function, if you want to access the result from some programming language you should use something like `SELECT myfunction('text');`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, try this,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `myfunction`(Name varchar(20))
RETURNS int
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

  DECLARE returnVal int;

  SELECT SUM(`Transaction`.Bought) INTO returnVal 
  FROM `Transaction` 
  WHERE `Transaction`.Name = Name;

  RETURN returnVal;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Same problem... Any other ideas?

Comment: Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Comment: Sorry.. Still an error. Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

Comment: ok, the function saved but returns nothing... When I run the query with hard coded params, it works fine.. Is something wrong with the declaration or return of returnVal?

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter //
create function myfun1234 (i int,j int)
returns int 
begin 
      declare x int ;
       declare    y int ;
        declare  z int ;
      set x=10;
      set y=20;
      if (1<=x && j>=y )then 
      set z=i+j;
      end if;
    return z;
      end; //


-- error1   FUNCTION myfun12 ended without RETURN
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR 1320 (42000): No RETURN found in FUNCTION apple.addition

When I tried to create `addition()` function without [RETURN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/return.html#:%7E:text=The%20RETURN%20statement%20terminates%20execution,procedures%2C%20triggers%2C%20or%20events.) statement as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION addition(value INT) RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
UPDATE test SET num = num + value;
SELECT num INTO value FROM test;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

So, I set `RETURN` statement to `addition()` function as shown below, then I could create `addition()` function without error:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION addition(value INT) RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
UPDATE test SET num = num + value;
SELECT num INTO value FROM test;
RETURN value; -- Here
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```