# MySQL, create a simple function

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures

I want to create a simple MySQL function, I have this MySQL procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getUser(gU INT)
   SELECT * FROM Company
   WHERE id_number = gU;

CALL getUser(2);
```

I need some help making this into a MySQL function.  What are the pros and cons of using a function over a procedure?

Comment: stored procedures can do most anything you want. they're simply a way of encapsulating a lot of logic behind a simple name, basically the same as in any programming language. they don't HAVE to select/update/whatever. When you say "function", do you mean a UDF?

Comment: Oh I see. I don't know what UDF means but by function I mean a stored function, in MySQL. Syntax is like CREATE FUNCTION etc.

Comment: MariaDB:
CREATE FUNCTION fFullname ( id INT(12) ) 
RETURNS CHAR(100) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' DETERMINISTIC
RETURN ( SELECT fullname FROM table_user WHERE user_id = id );

Comment: See [MySQL CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740932/mysql-create-function-syntax)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

this is a mysql function example. I hope it helps. (I have not tested it yet, but should work)

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS F_TEST //
CREATE FUNCTION F_TEST(PID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR
BEGIN
/*DECLARE VALUES YOU MAY NEED, EXAMPLE:
  DECLARE NOM_VAR1 DATATYPE [DEFAULT] VALUE;
  */
  DECLARE NAME_FOUND VARCHAR DEFAULT "";

    SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME INTO NAME_FOUND FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID = PID;
  RETURN NAME_FOUND;
END;//
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on ' DECLARE NAME_FOUND VARCHAR DEFAULT ""; ' What is DEFAULT ""? I assume NAME_FOUND is a variable you've made?

Comment: DEFAULT "" is a default value for NAME_FOUND which is the variable I use to store the result of the query. It is also optional and not mandatory.

Comment: Where the comment is. ' NOM_VAR1 DATATYPE [DEFAULT]  ' do I need to fill anything in there, or I can delete that? Because ATM there's syntax error in the NAME_FOUND part, IDK why.

Comment: You can delete all between the /* and */. Those were comments to explain "Declare" statement

Comment: @AlejandroBastidas - And how do you call this function? (maybe in SP or in query editor)

Comment: @zameeramir  to call a function just use "select function_name(parameter);" in this case  it woud be "select F_TEST(345);" where 345 would be the employee id as an example.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 19):

### MySQL function example:

**Open the mysql terminal:**

```
el@apollo:~$ mysql -u root -pthepassword yourdb
mysql>
```

**Drop the function if it already exists**

```
mysql> drop function if exists myfunc;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

**Create the function**

```
mysql> create function hello(id INT)
    -> returns CHAR(50)
    -> return 'foobar';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

**Create a simple table to test it out with**

```
mysql> create table yar (id INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)
```

**Insert three values into the table yar**

```
mysql> insert into yar values(5), (7), (9);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**Select all the values from yar, run our function hello each time:**

```
mysql> select id, hello(5) from yar;
+------+----------+
| id   | hello(5) |
+------+----------+
|    5 | foobar   |
|    7 | foobar   |
|    9 | foobar   |
+------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Verbalize and internalize what just happened:**

You created a function called hello which takes one parameter.  The parameter is ignored and returns a `CHAR(50)` containing the value 'foobar'.  You created a table called yar and added three rows to it. The select statement runs the function `hello(5)` for each row returned by yar.

Answer (score -4):

Try to change `CREATE FUNCTION F_TEST(PID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR`  this portion to 
`CREATE FUNCTION F_TEST(PID INT) RETURNS TEXT`

and change the following line too.

`DECLARE NAME_FOUND TEXT DEFAULT "";`

It should work.

Comment: Right. this worked for me. in fact it seems `VARCHAR` is not a valid type, `VARCHAR(50)` or `TEXT` are.