# Running SELECT statement inside a Function in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use a select statement inside a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_Id (d DATE) RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
DECLARE @retval INTEGER
SELECT id 
    from date_store c
    WHERE c.start_date <= d && c.end_date >= d
RETURN @retval
END
```

I am not sure if I have written this function correctly as I am not able to run it. Basically what I need is to call this function in order to get a id based on a date range given in the table date_store.

I am new to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional `&&` does not exists in SQL. Use `AND` instead.
Also you need to assign the returned variable with `SELECT id INTO @retval`.
Replace INTEGER by `INT` as well and do not forget about the semicolons.
It will be something like this (not tested)

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_Id (d DATE) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE @retval INT;
SELECT id INTO @retval
    FROM date_store c
    WHERE c.start_date <= d AND c.end_date >= d;
RETURN @retval;
END
```

[MySQL function with SELECT statment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606900/how-to-create-a-simple-get-query-with-a-function-mysql)

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@retval INTEGER
 SELECT id