# I am storing my query string with dynamic php variables in mysql DB and how can i retrive with actual values

Tags: php, mysql

I stored this query in table.: `"Select * from tbl_customer where bookingDate=$date"`

```
$tableResult[$i]['condition'] = "Select * from tbl_customer where bookingDate=$date";

$date = Date('Y-m-d');

$anotherVariable = $tableResult[$i]['condition'];

echo $anotherVariable;
```

This echo prints same string. How can I get following result :

```
Select * from tbl_customer where bookingDate=2014-06-10
```

Is any solution available?

Comment: Sidenote: `$date` needs to be bound with quotes as should `2014-06-10` otherwise, SQL will interpret the hyphens as a mathematical problem; such as a minus (sign).

Comment: The php is replacing the $date for its value. In the query, use like this: \$date

Comment: consider this string i have stored in db. Select * from tbl_customer where id=$i; $tableResult[$x]['condition']="Select * from tbl_customer where id=$i";
$i=1; $query=$tableResult[$x]['condition']; echo $query; result should be following Select * from tbl_customer where id=1

Comment: Consider a re-write. Use prepared statements and bind your variables instead—this is more secure and will almost definitely get you where you are trying to go. http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to store php code that generates a sql statement in a database. You've got to evaluate this string ... and eval() is most times evil. In this case I'm sure it is.

Comment: Finally i have solved this problem using eval() method. Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = Date('Y-m-d');
$tableResult[$i]['condition'] = "Select * from tbl_customer where bookingDate=$date";
$anotherVariable = $tableResult[$i]['condition'];
echo $anotherVariable;
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

The value of $tableResult[$i]['condition'] was set in line 1.

At that time, $date has not been set yet.

So actually you will get a warning of quoting undefined variable.

Define $date in line 2 will not update the value of $tableResult[$i]['condition']. Calling its value in line 3 won't update it either.

All you need to do is to define $date before $tableResult[$i]['condition'].

```
$date = Date('Y-m-d');

$tableResult[$i]['condition'] = "Select * from tbl_customer where bookingDate=$date";

$anotherVariable = $tableResult[$i]['condition'];

echo $anotherVariable;
```

Comment: Select * from tbl_customer where bookingDate=$date . I am stored this string in database. My problem is i am not able to replace a value of variable, which i read from the database string.

Comment: If you want to pass variable to database, then you may want to create a  function or stored procedure in database. For your references. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606900/mysql-create-a-simple-function