# MYSQL server error when create a function

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

i have a function when i am run query than i got this error

CREATE FUNCTION createBuffer(
ponto POINT,
distancia INT
) RETURNS POLYGON BEGIN /** * * @description : Function to create a circle around a given point and a radius in meters * @author : Fernando Norte (fnorte at gmail dot com) * * @params : ponto POINT (geometry), distancia INT (in meters) * @return : Polygon (geometry) * **/ SET @angle =0;

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS createBuffer;
CREATE FUNCTION createBuffer(tragetPoint POINT, distance INT) RETURNS POLYGON

    BEGIN
    /**
     *
     * @description : Function to create a circle around a given point and a radius in meters
     * @author : Fernando Norte (fnorte at gmail dot com)
     *
     * @params : tragetPoint POINT (geometry), distance INT (in meters)
     * @return : Polygon (geometry)
     *
     **/
        SET @angle = 0; 
        SET @buffer = ''; # point collection string
        SET @firstPoint = ''; # to close to polygon 
        SET @xP = X(tragetPoint);  # Lat of given point
        SET @yP = Y(tragetPoint); # Long of given point
        SET @radius = (distance / 111200); # Conversion from meters to decimal degres (number to confirm)

        REPEAT
            # Algorithm to put the points around the center
            SET @Nx = @xP + @radius * COS(@angle);  
            SET @Ny = @yP + @radius * SIN(@angle);

            # Concatenate the border point X,Y to the buffer string
            SET @buffer = CONCAT(@buffer, @Nx, ' ', @Ny, ', ');

            IF @angle = 0 THEN 
                # reserve the first point collected to close the polygon
                SET @firstPoint = CONCAT(@Nx, ' ', @Ny); 
            END IF;
            SET @angle = @angle + (2*PI()/20); # increment angle to put 20 points around the center
        UNTIL @angle >= (2*PI()) END REPEAT;

        # create WKT for the Polygon
        SET @buffer = CONCAT('POLYGON((', @buffer, @firstPoint, '))');

        RETURN GeomFromText(@buffer); 

    END
```

i cant understand what happen

Comment: Some the local variable are not declared..

Comment: angle, buffer , firstPoint, xP, yP...

Comment: it is only set veriable

Comment: Have you changed the delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me, test is the name of database.

```
use test;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION createBuffer(tragetPoint POINT, distance INT) RETURNS POLYGON
DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
    /**
     *
     * @description : Function to create a circle around a given point and a radius in meters
     * @author : Fernando Norte (fnorte at gmail dot com)
     *
     * @params : tragetPoint POINT (geometry), distance INT (in meters)
     * @return : Polygon (geometry)
     *
     **/

        SET @angle = 0; 
        SET @buffer = ''; # point collection string
        SET @firstPoint = ''; # to close to polygon 
        SET @xP = X(tragetPoint);  # Lat of given point
        SET @yP = Y(tragetPoint); # Long of given point
        SET @radius = (distance / 111200); # Conversion from meters to decimal degres (number to confirm)

        REPEAT
            # Algorithm to put the points around the center
            SET @Nx = @xP + @radius * COS(@angle);  
            SET @Ny = @yP + @radius * SIN(@angle);

            # Concatenate the border point X,Y to the buffer string
            SET @buffer = CONCAT(@buffer, @Nx, ' ', @Ny, ', ');

            IF @angle = 0 THEN 
                # reserve the first point collected to close the polygon
                SET @firstPoint = CONCAT(@Nx, ' ', @Ny); 
            END IF;
            SET @angle = @angle + (2*PI()/20); # increment angle to put 20 points around the center
        UNTIL @angle >= (2*PI()) END REPEAT;

        # create WKT for the Polygon
        SET @buffer = CONCAT('POLYGON((', @buffer, @firstPoint, '))');

        RETURN GeomFromText(@buffer); 

    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

[MySQL CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6740932/992406)