# What is wrong this simple function?

Tags: mysql

Here is a simple function I am creating for purpose of practice.  But receive the given error.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION Weighted_Average(n1 INT, n2 INT, n3 INT, n4 INT)
RETURNS INT
 DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
  DECLARE avg INT;
  SET avg = (n1 + n2 + n3*2 + n4*4)/8;
  RETURN avg;
 END;
 DELIMITER $$
```

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'n4*4)/8;   RETURN avg;  END' at line 6

I am comparing it to this post:

[MySQL CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740932/mysql-create-function-syntax)

Someone with experience can probably point out my mistake while I am getting no where.  I don't see what is wrong where the error is asking me to look.  Note: I am using workbench.

Comment: I tested it and it creates the function successfully. Cannot reproduce any error. I would guess there's something you're not telling us about the environment or the code.

Comment: Just a note: your second `DELIMITER` statement is supposed to return it to the default `;`.

Comment: Minus the delimiter statements, this works fine on SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4adc3c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you don't mean the following, mainly the bottom of it?

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS Weighted_Average;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION Weighted_Average(n1 INT, n2 INT, n3 INT, n4 INT)
RETURNS INT
 DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
  DECLARE avg INT;
  SET avg = (n1 + n2 + n3*2 + n4*4)/8;
  RETURN avg;
 END;$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

A `DELIMITER` is necessary for some client-side environments to delineate the beginning and end of blocks, and to change the end-of-lines for statements.

As the `DELIMITER` is defaulted to `;` out of the box, we know how to end a sql line with it, and never think about it. Until ...

When it comes to specialty blocks like `CREATE PROCEDURE` , `FUNCTION`, `EVENT`, `TRIGGER`, there needs to be some protocol for the client and server to know where the whole thing ends.

So, for clients like MySQL Workbench and similar, we use `DELIMITER` blocks. We change it to something funny up top, code as usual, and do the ending as seen above. Setting the `DELIMITER` back to our normal `;`

They are not needed for PHPMyAdmin. And presumably not so for [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: I would feel better if I know what is DELIMITER for, and then what is happening when I take the $$ signs and enter them following the END;