# Error 1064 in stored procedures

Tags: mysql

I get this error in the following stored procedure `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1; OPEN cur1; count' at line 13`

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS cursor_example
$$
CREATE PROCEDURE cursor_example()
   READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
   DECLARE i_Name CHAR(3);
   DECLARE i_SurfaceArea FLOAT(10,2);

   DECLARE done     INT DEFAULT 0;

   DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
     SELECT Name, SurfaceArea
      FROM country

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

    OPEN cur1;
    country_loop:LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO i_Name, i_SurfaceArea;
        IF done=1 THEN
            LEAVE country_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP country_loop;
    CLOSE cur1;

END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Just generally how the whole procedure is suppose to work and what is it for.
Thanks.

Comment: What does 'correct error' mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing a semi-colon after `FROM country`. Use the following pattern:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS cursor_example;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE cursor_example()
   READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
   DECLARE i_Name CHAR(3);
   DECLARE i_SurfaceArea FLOAT(10,2);

   DECLARE done     INT DEFAULT 0;

   DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
     SELECT Name, SurfaceArea
      FROM country;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

    OPEN cur1;
    country_loop:LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO i_Name, i_SurfaceArea;
        IF done=1 THEN
            LEAVE country_loop;
        END IF;

        -- right here is where you do stuff with those variables

    END LOOP country_loop;
    CLOSE cur1;

END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

> I don't understand with the example is trying to FETCH cur1 INTO in
>   the example is for?

Remember that the `CURSOR` is just a select stmt. It can be really complicated with joins, you name it. But in the end it has a select column list. In your case it has 2 columns coming back. So the `FETCH`, one row at a time, brings the current row into `LOCAL VARIABLES` (in the respective order from the cursor list to the variables you list). You declared those `LOCAL VARIABLES` in your `DECLARE`s.

When you are out of rows, the `HANDLER` sets `done` to 1 and you bail out of the loop.

As for the `DELIMITER` read the last half of this answer of mine [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39475768).

> Just generally how the whole procedure is suppose to work and what is
>   it for?

Described above mostly. Cursors are for procedural handling of data returned. Allowing you to inject procedural thinking into solving problems. By the way they are terribly slow and should be avoided whenever possible. They are typically a crutch for devs new to SQL that can't get their head into how to do work with sets and relations. That is, the way high performance RDBMS's excel at.

That said, experienced SQL devs are known to use them for tricky situations.

Comment: The semi colon fixes the error, but now upon giving the command: CALL cursor_example(); nothing happens.  I see the comment you wrote between END IF and END LOOP, that makes me think some more statements would give further use of the CURSOR in this stored procedure.

Comment: You do need to do something cuz otherwise you are just setting variables. Look at this trivial example for a guy that was new to it http://stackoverflow.com/a/39553173

Comment: You could take individual iterations of `i_Name` and  `i_SurfaceArea`  and do something with them. But all of that is undefined in what your intent is.