# Keep getting this error in SQL when creating a function. Fix?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `f_media`(
   `f_Date` DATE,
   `f_mediaexposure` VARCHAR(30), 
   `f_sentiment` VARCHAR(30)
) 
RETURNS INT(10)  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE v_result INT;

    SELECT v_result := COUNT(*) 
    FROM media_1 
    WHERE Mediumcat LIKE '%f_mediaexposure%' AND
       Date = f_Date AND
       sentiment = f_sentiment;
    RETURN v_result 
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

This doesn't work for me. Anyone know what i am doing wrong? just a beginner in SQL. Already tried the delimiter but still no luck.

1064 - Er is iets fout in de gebruikte syntax bij ':= COUNT(*) FROM media_1 WHERE Mediumcat LIKE '%f_mediaexposure%' AN' in regel 10

Comment: *Keep getting this error* ... which one?

Comment: Please refer this question posted earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740932/mysql-create-function-syntax

Comment: You miss the semicolons after each separate statement and the delimiter changing before and after the function creation

Comment: Tried all those things and also the error i get is in the post.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need:

- `delimiter`
- `:=`
- fix the parentheses.

In addition, you should name the parameters you are using more clearly and use semicolons:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `f_media`(
    `f_Date` DATE,
    `f_mediaexposure` VARCHAR(30), 
    `f_sentiment` VARCHAR(30)
) 
RETURNS INT(10)  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE v_result INT;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_result
    FROM media_1 
    WHERE Mediumcat LIKE '%f_mediaexposure%' AND
          Date = f_Date AND
          sentiment = f_sentiment;
     RETURN v_result 
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Sadly it still gives me this error: 1064 - Er is iets fout in de gebruikte syntax bij ':= COUNT(*) 
    FROM media_1 
    WHERE Mediumcat LIKE '%f_mediaexposure%' AN' in regel 10

Comment: `SELECT v_result := COUNT(*)` doesn't look like a valid syntax. One option is to change to `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_result`, at least in one function.

Comment: @wchiquito Thanks a lot man! It has compiled now.