# MySQL Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: sql, mysql, database, mysql-error-1064, mysql-function

```
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE FUNCTION fnc_credit_custstatus
    RETURNS VARCHAR(6) DETERMINISTIC
     BEGIN
     DECLARE custstatus VARCHAR(6);
     IF CustCredit>='1000',THEN SET custstatus='VIP';
     ELSEIF CustCredit<'1000',THEN SET custstatus='NONVIP';
   END IF;
   RETURN (custstatus);
   END//
   DELIMITER ;
```

Query:

```sql
CREATE function fnc_credit_custstatus returns varchar(6) deterministic 
begin DECLARE custstatus VARCHAR(6); if CustCredit>='1000...
```

> Error Code: 1064
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(6) deterministic
> begin
> DECLARE custstatus VARCHAR(6);
> if CustCredit>=' at line 2

Comment: try renove the comma after the if condition  IF CustCredit>='1000' THEN

Comment: DELIMITER //
      CREATE FUNCTION fnc_credit_custstatus
      RETURNS VARCHAR(6) DETERMINISTIC
      BEGIN
     DECLARE custstatus VARCHAR(6);
     IF CustCredit>=1000,THEN SET custstatus='VIP';
     ELSEIF CustCredit<1000,THEN SET custstatus='NONVIP';
     END IF;
     RETURN custstatus;
     END //
     DELIMITER ;

Comment: I tried, but it still wrong

Comment: IF CustCredit>=1000,THEN SET ??? you have not removed  any comma  you have also comma after the endif

Comment: Why are you testing custcredit agains a string - is custcredit a string also? (not directly related to your problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove comma

```
    DELIMITER //
        CREATE FUNCTION fnc_credit_custstatus
        RETURNS VARCHAR(6) DETERMINISTIC
         BEGIN
         DECLARE custstatus VARCHAR(6);
         IF CustCredit>=1000 THEN SET custstatus='VIP';
         ELSEIF CustCredit<1000 THEN SET custstatus='NONVIP';
       END IF;
       RETURN (custstatus);
       END//
       DELIMITER ;
```

(and use proper  comparision data type)

Comment: It doesn't show my Error, but why it doesn't show that I created FUNCTION succeeded？

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DETERMINISTIC

When I tried to create `addition()` function without **return value type** as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
                                    -- Here
CREATE FUNCTION addition(value INT) 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
UPDATE test SET num = num + value;
SELECT num INTO value FROM test;
RETURN value;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

So, I set **return value type** to `addition()` function as shown below, then I could create `addition()` function without error:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
                                    -- Here
CREATE FUNCTION addition(value INT) RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
UPDATE test SET num = num + value;
SELECT num INTO value FROM test;
RETURN value;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```