# Detecting spammers with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, spam

I see an ever increasing number of users signing up on my site to just send duplicate SPAM messages to other users. I've added some server side code to detect duplicate messages with the following mysql query:

```
  SELECT count(content) as msgs_sent 
    FROM messages 
   WHERE sender_id = '.$sender_id.' 
GROUP BY content having count(content) > 10
```

The query works well but now they're getting around this by changing a few charctersr in their messages.  Is there a way to detect this with MySQL or do I need to look at each grouping returned from MySQL and then use PHP to determine the percentage of similarity?

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Not an answer: MySQL fulltext search indexes can detect "similar" text.  So can numerous other search technologies.

Comment: MySQL's [`FULLTEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) search might help with it's [boolean mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322917/how-to-compute-similarity-between-two-strings-in-mysql

Comment: hope your using a CAPTCHA, and email varification

Comment: What other data do you have access to? Timestamps? Are they getting users by they're ID or in ABC order? You might be able to find other patterns...

Comment: They're getting users by IDs. Yes I use CAPTCHA, but not email verification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fulltext Match**

You could look at implementing something similar to the `MATCH` example [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

```
mysql> SELECT id, body, MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
    -> ('Security implications of running MySQL as root') AS score
    -> FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
    -> ('Security implications of running MySQL as root');
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
| id | body                                | score           |
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
|  4 | 1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ... | 1.5219271183014 |
|  6 | When configured properly, MySQL ... | 1.3114095926285 |
+----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**So for your example, perhaps:**

```
SELECT id, MATCH (content) AGAINST ('your string') AS score
FROM messages 
WHERE MATCH (content) AGAINST ('your string')
    AND score > 1;
```

Note that to use these functions your `content` column would need to be a `FULLTEXT` index.

**What is `score` in this example?**

It is a `relevance value`. It is computed through the process described below:

> Every correct word in the collection and in the query is weighted
>   according to its significance in the collection or query.
>   Consequently, a word that is present in many documents has a lower
>   weight (and may even have a zero weight), because it has lower
>   semantic value in this particular collection. Conversely, if the word
>   is rare, it receives a higher weight. The weights of the words are
>   combined to compute the relevance of the row.

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) page.

Comment: How is the score value relevant?  Can I use this to determine a percentage of how similar messages are? Thanks

Comment: Trying it now but I receive an error: #1210 - Incorrect arguments to AGAINST My query: SELECT id, MATCH (content) AGAINST (content) AS score
FROM messages WHERE MATCH (content) AGAINST (content)  AND score > 1;

Comment: The `AGAINST()` argument [must be a constant string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-restrictions.html).