# How do I use WHERE LIKE properly in a mysql prepared statement?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to puzzle out how to add a `LIKE` to this prepared statement.

```
SELECT convention_name FROM events_master 
WHERE (convention_name = ?);
```

The goal is to see if the convention name is similar to something that already exists in `convention_name`.  I do understand that it checks for an exact match already.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess, it is java, is not it?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
 String query = "SELECT convention_name FROM events_master WHERE convention_name like ?";
 PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(query);
 stm.setString(1, "%car%");
```

Your argument may contain wildchar %, then it will find for example card, scart ..

If this substring match is not enough, then you can use soundex algorithm to find similar strings. See [how to compute similarity between two strings in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322917/how-to-compute-similarity-between-two-strings-in-mysql) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT convention_name FROM events_master 
WHERE (convention_name LIKE 'partofname' + '%');

The % character is a wild char so if you put it in the back it will search for anything that begins with 'partofname' + blah appended to it.

if it's Like = '%partofname%' then partofname could have characters before or after it.

Comment: this is not prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

> If SQL LIKE clause is used along with % characters, then it will work
>   like a meta character (*) in UNIX while listing out all the files or
>   directories at command prompt.
>
> Without a % character, LIKE clause is very similar to equals sign
>   along with WHERE clause.

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare(SELECT convention_name FROM events_master 
WHERE convention_name LIKE ?");

$sql->execute(array('%'.$yourSearchString.'%'));
```