# PHP + MYSQL, something softer tham SOUNDS LIKE or configurable

Tags: php, mysql

I need something softer than SOUNDS LIKE or I need to configure it abit.

I have table with cities for example: "London"
I want to have up to one letter mistake in query.

When user will write: "Londom", I still want MYSQL to select London. But if user will write London with 2 letters wrong I don't want to select London anymore. So I just want SOUNDS LIKE with 1 letter treshold.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an [Edit Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) match. Problem is that these kinds of matches are *really* expensive, since indexing can't help make them faster, and you'll typically have to implement it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds/Soundex will be useless in this case:

There is solution:

[how to compute similarity between two strings in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322917/how-to-compute-similarity-between-two-strings-in-mysql)

Yo Can do this also in PHP- using levenshtein() function:

```
<?php
$sMySTR = "London";

$string1 = "Londam";
$string2 = "Londom";
$string2 = "London";

$check1 = levenshtein(sMySTR, $string1);
$check2 = levenshtein(sMySTR, $string2);
$check3 = levenshtein(sMySTR, $string3);

echo $check1." "; 
echo $check2." "; 
echo $check3." "; 
?>
```

Output will be:

2
1
0