# join with compatible percent

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to compare two large data tables with information of customers, only thing is compatible that is addresses of customers.  But people makes typos. Is there a function where I can compare string with compability procent? Like if table1.address 90% equals table2.address then it will return true.

Comment: You may use such thing as levenshtein distance. Brief overview & code available in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6392380/2637490). But the fact, that your data set is large - should at least make you thin about using similarity again. If it's only for one query, only once - it's ok. But if there's an intention to make it part of some functionality - then it's a design flaw. You should instead create solid relation between those two tables

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is a string distance calculation. As I know there is no built-in functions to do this in MySQL (fix me).

A widely used algorithm is the `Levenshtein distance`. This algorithm calculates the `distance` (the count of alterations have to be made to make 2 strings the same).
You can find the pseudo code on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#The_algorithm)

Here is an implementation in MySQL: http://openquery.com.au/blog/levenshtein-mysql-stored-function

If you divide the `distance` with the `length of the longest string`, you'll get the `Levenshtein distance ratio`. This is what you are looking for.

After you create the functions in your database, you can use it as a `WHERE` condition or as the part of the `ON` clause in `JOIN`s.

Here is a link to an implementation of the `Levenshtein distance ratio`
http://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/levenshtein-and-levenshtein_ratio-functions-for-mysql/