# How to return results if more than 60% of string is matching

Tags: php, sql

I have a table where product name are saved. I want to execute a select query statement where 60% or more results is matching

For example: If somebody types "verifone 500",
then the product:

1) **verifone vx500**
2)  **verifone5**
3)  **verifon00**
4) **verifone 50"** 
should be matched as they are 60% or more than same as searched product. I have tried this code

```
select `product_name` from product_data where `product_name` LIKE '%verifone 500%'
```

but not getting desired result.

Hope any body can help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322917/how-to-compute-similarity-between-two-strings-in-mysql

Comment: You could chop the search term down to 60% so `LIKE '%verifon%'.

Comment: If your db engine supports levenschtein distance, you can use that.

read more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 0):

You should go with `FULLTEXT` search for `MyISAM` table engine!

If your table engine is MyISAM then create FULLTEXT index for field `product_name`.

Then try query like:

```
SELECT `product_name`, MATCH (`product_name`) AGAINST ('verifone 500' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS match
FROM `product_data`
HAVING `match` > 0.5
ORDER BY `match` DESC
```

Comment: I have tried your code but its giving me error like this "Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list"

Comment: Because you don't created a FULLTEXT index to column `product_name`.