# mysql Want to check similar text using MATCH AGAINST. But get result even if one word match

Tags: mysql

For example mysql table like

```
TextColumn                  
------------------------
Full Metal Dog Guard for Passat Estate protecting rear seats and above
```

User types some text. I want to check if in mysql exists similar text to the typed text

```
$user_input = 'Full';
```

query like this

```
SELECT TextColumn FROM table WHERE MATCH(TextColumn) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 1

$stmt_for_duplicate->execute( array( $user_input ) );
$duplicate_data = $stmt_for_duplicate->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And get

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
    [TextColumn] => Full Metal Dog Guard for Passat Estate protecting rear seats and above 
    )

)
```

So only one word ('Full') is the same as in `TextColumn` and i get that result is similar

Seems i incorrectly use `MATCH AGAINST`.

Please, advice how to use correctly? May be I can add some percentage somehow? Or may be exists another simple and fast solution?

**Another way** but it is not effective (change one letter and get "as if not similar"). So better to use `MATCH ... AGAINST` but `AGAINST` must contain some sentence

I do not know how effective is such solution, but here it is (please, advice if can improve something).

So I have user input. I create array from certain number of first words

```
 $array_from_input = explode( " ", ( substr( (trim($_POST['user_input'])),0,150 ) ) );
```

Then create query and data

```
$part_of_sql_check_similar = '';
foreach( $array_from_input as $i_array_from_input => $v_array_from_input ) {

if( $i_array_from_input == 0 ){
$part_of_sql_check_similar .= 'TextColumn LIKE ? ';
}
else{
$part_of_sql_check_similar .= 'AND TextColumn LIKE ? ';
}

$data_check_similar[] = '%'. trim($v_array_from_input). '%';

}
```

And then select

```
try {
$stmt_for_duplicate = $db->prepare( '
SELECT 
Id FROM table_name 
WHERE '. 
$part_of_sql_check_similar. 
'LIMIT 1
;' );

$stmt_for_duplicate->execute( $data_check_similar );
$duplicate_data = $stmt_for_duplicate->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

In such way i check if one particular row contains all the words from user's input. All works, but how about performance? Seems slow?

Comment: Expect for example if 70% of words matches

Comment: @user2118559 . . . Percentage matches are based on the word count of the *query* not the *text*.  So, `'full'` has a 100% match rate.

Comment: So I can not use `MATCH AGAINST` in my situation (if I want to check if at least 70% of words is the same)?

Comment: You can use a hack :count all the words in a row,use a COUNT(*) when you search for a particular word,divide the COUNT(*) over the number of rows and use that in your condition.But its awful and why do you need 70% anyway?

Comment: User posts an ad. I want to check if too similar ad already exists

Comment: Maybe something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322917/how-to-compute-similarity-between-two-strings-in-mysql Also google for `check text similarity php` lost of nice results