# Getting first record that satisfies lef-most condition in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

My main goal is to search in a column for a specific value (say *word*). If it doesn't exist, want to find the first that matches *word%* or *wor%* or *wo%* or *w%*.

In "English", the query would read like: "look for 'word' and return it if it exists. If not, look for the first word that has the maximum same prefix as 'word'".

I can write

```
SELECT word FROM words WHERE word = 'word' or word LIKE 'word%' or ... LIMIT 1;
```

I was trying to order by alphabetically, but it won't work (wo comes before wor). Also, can't order in reverse order, or 'wordy' will come before 'word'.

My current idea is just to call the database n times, where n = length(word). But I would like to know if there is any kind of 'short-circuit OR' in SQL -- MySQL/MariaDB, to be precise.

**Example**

DB has 'w', 'word', 'wording', want to search by 'word' and retrieve 'word' only.

DB has 'z', 'zab', 'zac', 'ze', 'zeb' want to search by 'za' and get 'zab'

Comment: post some sample input and output...

Comment: The 2nd example is wrong. You'll get 'z';

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz my bad. Fixed what I want Note that your answer bellow will fail in the second example.

Comment: I want the exact entry if it exists. If not, the first word with the longest prefix (that is what my SQL query would read if we had short-circuit in SQL). - adding this to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a [string distance algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322917/how-to-compute-similarity-between-two-strings-in-mysql). The string distance algorithm tells you how many changes are needed to change the current word into the desired word. The idea is that you give all your words a string distance and sort ascending on the distance. An exact match will have 0, a missing or extra letter will have 1.

Not exactly the answer to your question, but I am hoping it is actually what you were looking for. You may also be interested in [word stems](https://github.com/johnpcarty/mysql-porter-stemmer) which will go nicely with this.

**EDIT**

Extending my answer with a solution to your actual query.
Add a funtion:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `WORDRANK`(`a` VARCHAR(150), `b` VARCHAR(150)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE rank INT DEFAULT 0;

    WHILE rank < LENGTH(a) DO
        IF rank = 0 AND b = a THEN RETURN rank;
        ELSEIF rank = 0 AND b LIKE CONCAT(a, "%") THEN RETURN rank + 1;
        ELSEIF b LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(a, LENGTH(a) - rank), "%") THEN RETURN rank + 2;
        END IF;
        SET rank = rank + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN rank + 100;
END
```

Then create a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getClosestMatch`(IN `q` VARCHAR(150))
BEGIN
    SELECT
        word
    FROM words
    WHERE word LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(q, 1),"%")
    ORDER BY WORDRANK(q, word), word
    LIMIT 1;
END
```

In order to get the desired results, we need to rank each word based on your desired algorithm, which we defined in the WORDRANK function. The stored procedure is so we have a generic way of executing the query.

Comment: Yes, that would be an option, but was trying something simpler :-)

Comment: Complex, but seems to work. Just added 'word' to the ORDER BY, in order to have it sorted alphabetically when there are two words with same rank.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: Words are ASCII, minimum length = 1, maximum value < 'ZZ'.
Assumption: VARCHAR input, no trail spaces.
Assumption: if 'word' is not there, but 'wording' and 'wordy' are there,
you want 'wording' not 'wordy'.
Perhaps not simpler, but with a single SELECT statement ...

```
set @x = 'w'; /* or whatever word you want to search with */
 select * from words
 where word <= concat(@x,'zz')
 and (word like concat(@x,'%') or @x like concat(word,'%'))
 order by length(word) <> length(@x),
 case when length(word) = length(@x) then 1 else 0 end asc,
 case when length(word) > length(@x) then word else 'zz' end asc,
 word desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT word 
  FROM words
 WHERE word LIKE 'w%'
ORDER BY word;
```

Comment: walla? (a word that starts with 'w' and has no relation to `word`)

Comment: As I said, 'w' will come before 'word'.