# Find exactly text which contain column's value in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

```html
id   text_1          text_2
1    おはよう         おはよ
2    こんにちは       ちわー
3    大丈夫           さよなら
4    でんわしたい     でんわしよう
```

I have DB same above.

I want to search with input: おはよう大丈夫？

Expect result will match: id = 1 and id = 3.

Please help me how to query search in Mysql? Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL query will fetch your 2 ids for exact string matching

```
select id from TABLENAME where text_1 in ('おはよう','大丈夫');
```

You can also use `like` operator with `%` to fetch approximately strings id.

You might face encoding issue (文字化け）depending on your DB settings, so you might have to convert SJIS <-> UTF-8

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-cjk.html#faq-cjk-what-cjk-avail

Last but not least, **if you want to use the full string as a comparison criteria to select the rows**, then you can reuse the following code:

[how to compute similarity between two strings in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322917/how-to-compute-similarity-between-two-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: but my input is text include: おはよう大丈夫？
Not split 2 word おはよう and 大丈夫.

Comment: You have to split it somehow or how will you know which part goes in which field?

Comment: Yeah or you can implement your own comparison method based on hamming distances, or number of common char shared by the two strings

Comment: My input is same Chat text, maybe another way not need split it but still search above?

Comment: if you want to use the full string as a comparison criteria to select the rows, then you can reuse the following code:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322917/how-to-compute-similarity-between-two-strings-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks you very much. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

select id from TABLENAME where text_1 REGEXP "おはよう大丈夫"

Comment: i used this but result is empty.

Comment: my input is: おはよう大丈夫. Not split 2 words.