# SQL Query to find relevant result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a sql table with one varchar column. Some of the data it contains is like:

```
sadkjlsakjd
Physics Test 2
Test
Test 1
P Test C
Physics Test None
dstestsad
```

Now, I need a query that gives the most relevant record first when I search with 'Test' keyword. I am expecting:

```
Test
Test 1
<Then other records where Test comes in between>
```

I have some how achieved this query with Temp table and intersection but not at all happy with what I written. I have a feeling that there should be something easy and fast.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Is that line with data representing several different records or just one record?

Comment: What defines the relevance? The string you are searching starts with the keyword?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636911/how-to-find-strings-which-are-similar-to-given-string-in-sql-server) addresses a similar issue, I think.

Comment: Did you try to use CONTAINS and FREETEXT and maybe CONTAINSTABLE and FREETEXTTABLE to generate a ranking value to decide on how many fields to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT colName 
FROM tableName 
WHERE colName LIKE '%Test%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN colName LIKE 'Test%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, colName
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I did not understand this. What I have been told till now is Order by 1 means sort by 1st column and order by 2 means sort by 2nd column

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM Your_Table WHERE Your_Column LIKE '%Test%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Your_Column LIKE 'Test%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,Your_Column
```

Answer (score 0):

I was intensely working on this recently by making a relevance query using SQL. I should probably write a paper or create an open source project but I'm too busy at work and at home so I'll be lazy I'll just write it in here.

**First** you'll need to understand that relevance calculations accuracy depends on how much data you collect as part of your query. So you'll need to weight performance vs accuracy. The more performant you want the queries the less data you want to read, but also the less accurate your results will be, so you'll need to find a balance and your data will tell you that.

**Second** you'll need to separate your relevance into separate criteria and provide some score mechanism the dummer the mechanism the better so it's easy to understand and then you can iterate from there. Sounds complicated but it does not have to be complicated.

#### Solution:

1. Well define your set of criteria
2. get multiple data samples larger than the limit that it's been requested 3. for each type of match and assign a boost factor score for example if you consider starts_with more relevant than contains the you could say starts_with score is 2 and contains score is 1
   4.then `UNION ALL` results into a single result set
3. Aggregate and sort the scores in descending order.
4. Adjust the scores to get better relevance based on your data.

Note:
When querying the extra data is very important so you can combine scores because one criteria could match one way another different records.
The higher the more accurate the results are going to be accuracy so make sure to query more times than the requested limit.

For example if you want the a limit of 10 then you'll probably want to query for at least `limit(10) * number_of_criteria_or_more(2)` => `TOP(10 * 2)` In my case I used 10x the number of requested rows so I can get a better sample and more relevant results.

#### Example using CTE (common table expressions)

```sql
-- starts_with criteria data
WITH StartsWith_Criteria_CTE AS (
  SELECT TOP (10 * 2) 2 AS score, test_column FROM test_table WHERE test_column LIKE 'test%'
),
-- contains criteria data
Contains_Criteria_CTE AS (
    SELECT TOP (10 * 2) 1 AS score, test_column FROM test_table WHERE test_column LIKE '%test%'
),
-- combine results using union all
CombinedScores_CTE AS (
   SELECT score, test_column FROM StartsWith_Criteria_CTE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT score, test_column FROM Contains_Criteria_CTE
),
-- Aggregate the scores
AggregatedScores_CTE (
   SELECT
   TOP (10)
     SUM(score) AS score,
     test_column
   FROM CombinedScores_CTE
   GROUP BY test_column
   ORDER BY score DESC
)
-- get your results
SELECT TOP (10) score, test_column FROM AggregatedScores_CTE;
```

##### Results with simple relevance score

You'll see 1 for the contains and 3 for the starts_with because contains and start_with overlap. Because of this overlap sometimes you'll need to adjust to balance the relevance scores.

| score | test_column |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Test 1 |
| 3 | Test |
| 3 | Test C |
| 1 | Physics Test 2 |
| 1 | dstestsad |
| 1 | Physics Test None |

This scoring algorithm is simple but works.
I've used a more complex score based on the difference of lengths on top of the score boost factor to differentiate when there is a tie to warrantee the proper order when calculating.

If you want a more complex matching with tie breaking scoring then you could update to the following.

#### Example with criteria tie breaker

```sql
-- starts_with criteria data
WITH StartsWith_Criteria_CTE AS (
  SELECT TOP (10 * 2)
    (LEN(test_column)/(LEN(test_column) - LEN('test') + 1.0)) * 2 + 2 AS score, 
    test_column
  FROM test_table WHERE test_column LIKE 'test%'
),
-- contains criteria data
Contains_Criteria_CTE AS (
    SELECT TOP (10 * 2)
     (LEN(test_column)/(LEN(test_column) - LEN('test') + 1.0)) * 1 + 1 AS score, 
     test_column FROM test_table
    WHERE test_column LIKE '%test%'
),
-- combine results using union all
CombinedScores_CTE AS (
   SELECT score, test_column FROM StartsWith_Criteria_CTE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT score, test_column FROM Contains_Criteria_CTE
),
-- Aggregate the scores
AggregatedScores_CTE (
   SELECT
   TOP (10)
     SUM(score) AS score,
     test_column
   FROM CombinedScores_CTE
   GROUP BY test_column
   ORDER BY score DESC
)
-- get your results
SELECT TOP (10) score, test_column FROM AggregatedScores_CTE;
```

#### Results with criteria tie breaker score calculation

| score | test_column |
| --- | --- |
| 15.0 | Test |
| 9.0 | Test 1 |
| 9.0 | Test C |
| 2.5 | dstestsad |
| 2.27 | Physics Test 2 |
| 2.21 | Physics Test None |

Seems a bit confusing why did `dstestsad` got a higher score if you could barely tell that `test` is in there? but it does have the least amount of characters. If we think this is a weird behavior maybe we should consider adding a new criteria that tells if the input is used as a word

#### Example using criteria tie breaker and with is_word criteria

```sql
-- starts_with criteria data
WITH StartsWith_Criteria_CTE AS (
  SELECT TOP (10 * 3)
    (LEN(test_column)/(LEN(test_column) - LEN('test') + 1.0)) * 3 + 3 AS score, 
    test_column
  FROM test_table WHERE test_column LIKE 'test%'
),
-- contains criteria data
Contains_Criteria_CTE AS (
    SELECT TOP (10 * 3)
     (LEN(test_column)/(LEN(test_column) - LEN('test') + 1.0)) * 1 + 1 AS score, 
     test_column FROM test_table
    WHERE test_column LIKE '%test%'
),
-- is a word criteria data
IsAWord_Criteria_CTE AS (
    SELECT TOP (10 * 3)
     (LEN(test_column)/(LEN(test_column) - LEN('test') + 1.0)) * 2 + 2 AS score, 
     test_column FROM test_table
    WHERE
      test_column LIKE 'test %' OR
      test_column LIKE '% test %' OR
      test_column LIKE '% test' OR
      test_column = 'test'
),
-- combine results using union all
CombinedScores_CTE AS (
   SELECT score, test_column FROM StartsWith_Criteria_CTE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT score, test_column FROM Contains_Criteria_CTE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT score, test_column FROM IsAWord_Criteria_CTE
),
-- Aggregate the scores
AggregatedScores_CTE (
   SELECT
   TOP (10) 
     SUM(score) AS score,
     test_column
   FROM CombinedScores_CTE
   GROUP BY test_column
   ORDER BY score DESC
)
-- get your results
SELECT score, test_column FROM AggregatedScores_CTE;
```

#### Results with additional is a word criteria

Now the results seems very relevant to the user.

| score | test_column |
| --- | --- |
| 30.0 | Test |
| 18.0 | Test 1 |
| 18.0 | Test C |
| 6.82 | Physics Test 2 |
| 6.64 | Physics Test None |
| 2.5 | dstestsad |

---

#### Simple approach

In your case you have only have 2 criteria and both `starts_with` and `contains` overlaps and if the data is fairly small you could probably rely on the order of the `UNION` to get all the data.

##### For example:

```sql
SELECT test_column FROM test_table WHERE test_column LIKE 'test%'
UNION ALL
SELECT test_column FROM test_table WHERE test_column LIKE '%test%' AND NOT test_column LIKE 'test%'
```