# Searching and sorting the query outputs after compare

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

my search query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `trades` where `app` = '1' AND (`unit` LIKE '%$search%' OR `keyword` LIKE '%$search%')
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql )){
```

and after it i need to compare and show like this:

```
similar_text(strtoupper($search), strtoupper($row['unit']), $similarity_pst);
  if (number_format($similarity_pst, 0) > 20){
echo $row['link'];
echo $row['unit'];
echo $row['keyword'];
//....
```

but i want before print value,  sort  all of in $row by percent 
on top 90% and then show 80 ...70%
and can show with pagination
thanks

Comment: Can you try either rank or use order by? RegExp is better than using Like operator :)

Comment: compelete query have it : ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT $start, $limit

Answer (score 0):

Be aware when using this function, that the order of passing the strings is very important if you want to calculate the percentage of similarity, in fact, altering the variables will give a very different result.

**Example:**

```
<?php 
    $var_1 = 'PHP IS GREAT'; 
    $var_2 = 'WITH MYSQL'; 

    similar_text($var_1, $var_2, $percent); 

    echo $percent; 
    // 27.272727272727 

    similar_text($var_2, $var_1, $percent); 

    echo $percent; 
    // 18.181818181818 
?>
```

You may also see the topic, discussed here: [How to find similar results and sort by similarity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338889/how-to-find-similar-results-and-sort-by-similarity)