# Less strict MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql

I know that MySQL queries are pretty exact. But I don't want it so exact.

If I have a query of cheeseburger. I want burger to return. Or cheese. Or even cheeseburgers.

Thanks!

Edit:  Cheeseburgers is not the only problem. It's for any word. Because I'm trying to build a search system. And I want similar words/ results considered/ returned also.

Comment: Is cheeseburgers the only problem or would you like the same thing to apply for words like `housecat` as well? (i.e. find both house and cat). Basically I think your question is not very clear.

Comment: Cheeseburgers is not the only problem. It's for any word. Because I'm trying to build a search system. And I want similar words/ results considered/ returned also.

Comment: That's what I thought. What you are trying to do is not a simple task I think, but there are solutions out there!

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to do what I need to accomplish? Even if you point me in the right direction that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LIKE` and `%`:

```
SELECT id, name FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE '%cheese%' OR name LIKE '%burger%'
```

**Edit**:

You might also be searching for [How to find similar results and sort by similarity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338889/how-to-find-similar-results-and-sort-by-similarity)

Comment: Not sure this is what the OP is looking for. Sounds to me like he wants to search for cheeseburger and find both cheese and burger.

Comment: If I were to do, %cheeseburger%, would cheese and burger be returned? Or does it not break down words

Comment: @MichaelKing No, you'd have to use Lucene or another search engine for that (maybe Levensthein, but it's slow on MySQL). Your best bet is to check the link I posted - it explains everything you need (and then you don't have to build your own search system which will be slower than something already built.)

Answer (score 0):

use [SOUNDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex):

```
select * from table where SOUNDEX(name)=SOUNDEX("burger") or  SOUNDEX(name)=SOUNDEX("cheese")
```

Comment: Note, from the manual: `This function, as currently implemented, is intended to work well with strings that are in the **English language only**. Strings in other languages may not produce reliable results.`

Answer (score 0):

Use

%cheese% OR %burger%

This will retun cheese, burger and cheeseburger also anything which has cheese and anything which has burger