# Auto correct spelling errors in web application

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, search, autocorrect

I develop web application i have search engine in it . I read the data from database . I built the search engine that can help to complete the word, but need to help to correct the spelling such as i write spelling this word is wrong i want to help and find the correct word such as do you mean spelling such as in Google search engine . help please I saw many links and can't find the right solution.

```
 <h2>Search</h2> 
  <form name="search" method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">
  Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" /> in 
  <Select NAME="field">
  <Option VALUE="fname">diseasename</option>
  <Option VALUE="lname">genename</option>
  </Select>
  <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
  </form>
  </html>
  <?php 
  //This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 
  if ($searching =="yes") 
  { 
  echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 

  //If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 
  if ($find == "") 
  { 
  echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term"; 
  exit; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) in the input text that you want to spell check. Then using [.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) send the value from the input text to the server and check if the value received it's similar to anything that you have in your database. Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3339034/3307382) regarding this last part.

So in general you do this in the html

```
<h2>Search</h2> 
<form name="search" method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">
Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" id="find" /> in 
<Select NAME="field">
<Option VALUE="fname">diseasename</option>
<Option VALUE="lname">genename</option>
</Select>
<input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
</form>
</html>

<script>
  $( "#search" ).keypress(function(event) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
           type:"POST" // or GET ,
           url: "search.php", // the url to the php file
           data: {value:value}, //send the value
           success:function( msg){
                //update your input text to indicate if you have an error
           },

      });
  });

<script>
```

And in the php you need to do something with this value. Depending what you want to do. If you want to show suggestion then it's something like the link I put before [(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3339034/3307382). But if you only want to check if the word exists then it's only something like this:

```
 <?php
  //some code
  $value = $_POST['value'];
  //connect to the data base and make stuff to prevent sql injection      
  $sql = "SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE name = '".$value."'"; //this is just an example
  ?>
```

Of course this is an extremely simple example. You could use [LIKE operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) or more complex stuff

Hope it helps