# How to find similar text in database?

Tags: php, mysql

We are creating a database of companies, and we would like to have unique company name. However, sometimes user enter them differently, i.e. some day they might enter "xyz, inc" and the other day they might enter it as "xyz inc." though the name are logically same, but not for database comparison purposes.

Is there any way I can find similar name in a MySQL database? We've already considered using `LIKE`, but decided against it.

Comment: Did you tried anything? Fulltext search engine, for example

Comment: actually I am just reading about how to do, and have no clue how to do it? I never use fulltext search, can you give me some guide.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338889/how-to-find-similar-results-and-sort-by-similarity) answer.

Comment: No - because it's only about - reading the manual. That [page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) has all needed explanations together with good examples. I don't think that copy-pasting manual page to SO answer would have any sense.

Comment: @AlmaDo I really didn't expect a copy paste manual, but You really help me out here. Thanks.

Comment: @mvw Yes, I was reading about such implementation, but they didn't make much sense to me. Sometime for starter such things are little complex to understand. But thanks, full text search did a decent job for my purpose at this moment.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this is to split your user input into words, and trim out punctuation:

```
"xyz, inc." becomes array("xyz", "inc")
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    company
WHERE
    name LIKE '%xyz%'
    OR name LIKE '%inc%';
```

To improve this, you could run the query once per word, and add weightings to them (you would therefore need a weighting table, and it might say that "inc" is a common word and thus does not count significantly). More weightings and more results would increase the ranking of each result.

Bear in mind though that this strategy may not be optimal from a performance perspective, if you have a large table, since `LIKE` performs full table scans. If you have 10K rows you'll be fine, but if you have 1M rows, you might not be. As always, you should try it on a representative database to see what performance is like in your case.

This is just a quick-and-simple solution, but you would have better results if you were to install a specific search system, such as ElasticSearch or Lucene.

Comment: Yup your idea is good, and I really thought of it, but I was looking something better than this. My DB is not big today, but who knows :). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Sumit: That's fair enough, although in general if some solutions have already been rejected, it is a good idea to note that in the question to start with. The next step is to consider Alma's recommendation of full-text search in the database (as this requires no additional software), and failing that, use a proper search indexer, as per my last paragraph.

Comment: (I've edited your question to reflect that. Perhaps you could edit it further to explain _why_ a `LIKE` solution is not good enough).

Comment: Thanks for editing, and thanks for guiding. Yes, as I mention in my comment I am going with his solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * From table Where company Like '%xyz%'

Select * From table Where company Like '%xyz' OR company Like '%inc'

Select * From table Where company Like 'xyz%' AND company Like 'inc%'
```

Use the `%` sign to search from at first side or place the `%` sign in last to match from last or put both side to match exact one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From table Where company Like '%xyz%'

Select * From table Where company Like '%xyz%' OR company Like '%inc%'

Select * From table Where company Like 'xyz%' AND company Like '%inc%'
```

Last one would work the best in your case