# SQL Multiple Row Subquery Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, json

I cannot get multiple rows of the Posts.body column to show up in the subquery.  I DO want subqueries and I haven't figured out a way around this MySQL restraint.  Please let me know if you need more information.

```
SELECT profile_picture, body, post_date, filename, username FROM Posts, Users 
WHERE Posts.IDUser = Users.IDUser 
  AND Posts.body LIKE (SELECT Posts.body FROM Posts WHERE Posts.IDUser = (SELECT Users.IDUser FROM Users WHERE Users.username = 'noah'))
ORDER BY `Posts`.`post_date` DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what the problem is exactly, but from what I can see it seems you need to use `IN` instead of `LIKE`:

```
SELECT profile_picture, body, post_date, filename, username FROM Posts, Users 
WHERE Posts.IDUser = Users.IDUser 
  AND Posts.body IN (SELECT Posts.body FROM Posts WHERE Posts.IDUser = (SELECT Users.IDUser FROM Users WHERE Users.username = 'noah'))
                 ^^ here
ORDER BY `Posts`.`post_date` DESC;
```

On the other hand the inner `SELECT`s seem unnecessary as you are already joining `Posts` and `Users` so you can probably simplify it a lot using just a join.

What exactly are you trying to select?

Comment: I just tried that and it returns all of the rows.  Is that supposed to happen?  I want to find similar text in the body column from the current user.

Comment: @user2793987 *Similar text* is pretty broad, do you mean to search for certain words or do you really want to analyze similaries? I doubt you can do the latter easily in sql.

Comment: Analyze similarities or really just wildcard it.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you are joining a table to itself, or using it in a subquery, you have to alias it.

So your inner query should be something like

```
(
  SELECT p.body 
  FROM Posts p 
  WHERE p.IDUser = something
)
```

I find it pretty hard to understand what you're trying to do with this query.  I have a feeling it could be greatly simplified but I'm not sure what data you are after.

Comment: I want to find all similar text from a specific user that they have posted in the body column of the table.  This is my json data: http://shipstudent.com/complaint_desk/similarPosts.php?username=noah

Comment: I essentially just want to wildcard the whole "body" column.

Comment: You can find a word or phrase within a string easily using LIKE, but finding keywords or selecting records where the difference falls within a certain tolerance is decidedly NOT easy.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338889/how-to-find-similar-results-and-sort-by-similarity) for more details

Comment: Hmm, so there is no way of obtaining multiple records out of a subquery?