# How to find the nearest string value from table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table name "test" having a column code (string format) and data is like:

```
U298765
U298799
U210430
U210499
B239856
```

Now I want to get data by input field entry. If a user write U298750, I want show the nearest value U298765 and for U210401,U210430.

Comment: `WHERE column < 'U298765' ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: @akina, I think < will not work. It can be > also. Mearest can be anywhere. Even same code may also exists.

Comment: [Hope this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373140/find-nearest-matching-strings-and-its-substrings-using-sql-query)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Define "near"...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the right function to fetch the number and then use following logic.

```
Select t.*
  From test t
Order by abs(Right(code, length(code)-1) - Right(your_input, length(your_input)-1))
Limit 1
```

I am consodering that you need the nearest based on numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
select  code from test
order by abs(abs(substring(code,2,length(code)))-abs(substring('U298750',2,length('U298750'))))
Limit 1
```

In place of 'U298750' use your input

Answer (score 0):

You seem to just want:

```
select t.*
from t
where code >= ?   -- the input value
order by code desc
limit 1;
```

The ordering of strings alphabetically is sufficient for getting the "next" value after the string.  There is no need to convert anything to numbers.