# MySQL Search Where String Contains

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like to search a MySQL database for author names. The issues is the same author name can be spelled (or entered into the database) in a variety of ways. I need to check for **similar** names.

A sample of my `authors` table is as follows;

```
+---------+-------------+
| id      | author      |
+---------+-------------+
| 1       | JK Rowling  |
+---------+-------------+
| 2       | J.K Rowling |
+---------+-------------+
| 3       | Rowling JK  |
+---------+-------------+
| 4       | Rowling J.K |
+---------+-------------+
| 5       | JK. Rowling |
+---------+-------------+
| 6       | Jim Jones   |
+---------+-------------+
```

I want to find all books by 'J.K Rowling', so the query I am using is;

```
SELECT *
FROM `authors`
WHERE `author` LIKE '%J.K Rowling%'
```

Returns `no results`.

```
SELECT *
FROM `authors`
WHERE `author` LIKE 'J.K Rowling%'
```

Returns `no results`.

```
SELECT *
FROM `authors`
WHERE `author` LIKE '%J.K Rowling'
```

Returns `no results`.

How should I structure the query in order to return **similar authors**.

Thanks

Comment: what is column `item_author` --  not in your sample.

Comment: isn't `item_author` suppose to be `author` ?

Comment: Apologies I have edited the question. Typo

Comment: Shouldn't this work:

    SELECT *
    FROM `authors`
    WHERE `item_author` LIKE '%rowling%'; ?

Comment: you need similarity. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338889/how-to-find-similar-results-and-sort-by-similarity

Comment: What is the datatype for the author column?   
SELECT * FROM `authors` WHERE `author` LIKE '%J.K Rowling%' should definitely return the row with id 2

Comment: The datatype is `varchar`. ` SELECT * FROM authors WHERE author LIKE '%J.K Rowling%' ` returns 0 results. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the similar name is Rowling, so I should try with this.

```
SELECT *
FROM `authors`
WHERE `author` LIKE '%Rowling%'
```

Comment: I'm unable to do that, I am searching a whole string. The whole string being whatever is in the row :/ Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use `%J.K Rowling%` which means the process will only search on rows that has `J.K Rowling` and no more no less. Based on your datatabe, there's no `J.K Rowling`on it. You might wanna try `Rowling` or something like that.

Comment: J.K Rowling is in the data set

Answer (score 0):

your problem is **"."**

According to the MySQL docs, the only special characters when using the LIKE operator are "%" (percent: matches 0, 1, or many characters) and "_" (underscore: matches one and only one character). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

A "." (period) does have special meaning for MySQL's REGEXP operator, but it should still match a literal period in your column. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran your MySQL code on https://paiza.io/

```
create table authors(id integer, author varchar(100));
insert into authors(id, author) values(1, "J.K Rowling");
insert into authors(id, author) values(2, "JK Rowling");
insert into authors(id, author) values(3, "Rowling JK");
insert into authors(id, author) values(4, "Rowling J.K");
insert into authors(id, author) values(5, "JK. Rowling");
insert into authors(id, author) values(6, "Jim Beam");

SELECT *
FROM `authors`
WHERE `author` LIKE '%J.K Rowling%'
```

and the result I got is:

```
id  author
1   J.K Rowling
```

So the code checks out, should be working, maybe your database settings are different somehow.