# mySQL - Find and group similar values with wildcard

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates, distinct

Hy guys,

i searched some questions on stackoverflow, but i found no solution for my problem :(

I have a table with some values of a internal search database:

```
ID    searchword     hits
1     php             200
2     html             88
3     php state        68
4     php statement    43
5     js               83
6     html img         48
7     html include     34
```

And so on...
I need a query to group searchwords, but also the similars.
For example I need this result for the table above:

```
 searchword
  php statement      (because 'php' and 'php statement' is similar)
  js                 (because it´s only one row and standalone)
  html img           (because 'html' is similar, it´s included)
  html include       (because 'html' is similar, it´s included)
```

Is that possible?
The query should not be static, because I don´t know all searchwords in the table. I think I need a DISTINCT and a LIKE query with wildcard (%)?!

But I don´t get it :(

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd24c/28

Regards
Ronny

Comment: php state isn't similar !?!

Comment: Its only a example. I build a fiddle for better understanding

Comment: you should build the sqlfiddle based on the question data.

Comment: FWIW, this kind of task rapidly becomes horrendously difficult in SQL.

Comment: So the GROUP BY should group (php, php state, php statement), (html, html img, html include), (js)...  if i understand your question correctly... how should the excepted results look like?

Comment: Unless you have the search keywords in somewhere else you **CAN'T** do this query. Also you need priorities for those keywords. What if a row is `PHP HTML` what group will you assign it?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza is right. It can be done if you want to assign group based on first word only.

Comment: @Harshil I thought about that but in the sql fidlle he have data like `46` and `4634` plus `inter` and `interface`

Comment: Hmm... i think about a subquery like ' WHERE searchword LIKE "% %" ' - and it should only group similar words. For example if i have "html", "php" and "html php" - it´s a result of 3 standalone hits.

Comment: You can use text search ... something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338889/how-to-find-similar-results-and-sort-by-similarity