# php and mysql search for users

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote this code to search users from mysql :

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = {$id} ");
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['username'];
    // ....
    echo "People also search :";
    // the people also search box
}
```

I want it so that when the user pages load in the bottom of the page be a box like this:

`Walter`

...

`People also search :`

`Bruce` `Kevin` `Jesse`

something like the Google when you search actors or ...

how could I do this ?

Comment: have you tried anything first?

Comment: no , i don't have any idea

Comment: what is your db scheme?  How are you checking to see if they are similar? maybe a table like searches for each user?  Need more info to help

Comment: Use AJAX to dynamically update the page

Comment: i use a table for all users and i want to create a column for this people also search

Comment: Then you are going to need to fill that column based on past searches like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you start by getting it to work with some random  values from the database response

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT username FROM `users");
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
     $rows[]=$row
}
//id of the user by which you have made the search
echo $rows[$id];
unset($rows[$id]);
echo "People also search :".PHP_EOL;
$rand_keys = array_rand($rows, 5);
foreach($rand_keys as $key){
    echo $rows[$key];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd need to keep a record of past searches and then when a new one is searched find all the people who searched for that in the past and find what else they searched for.

Comment: it would be a lot of search and i just want to show the similar users

Comment: OK, how do you define "similar"? If just similar names then you can do a text search https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: If you're using something else to define similar (eg permissions) then you'd need a way to compare those.

Comment: OK my initial one would be people who searched for this also searched for these. If you just want ones with similar text (eg correct for spelling mistakes) then this question would probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338889/how-to-find-similar-results-and-sort-by-similarity

Comment: But if you want how google works when searching for actorsthen you're going to need a list of attribute that make the results "similar". In that movie example you'll get actors who worked on the same movies as the person you searched for so you'll need to have a database of connections and return the 3 with the most number of connections to what you searched for.