# yii2 query match partial word

Tags: yii2

So i'm working a little search tool for a website but I ran into an little issue, when I enter a word and if this word is present it will return the results, but when i search on this word and add a extra character to it wil not return any results.

When I search on the word 'tool' it will return the results as this word is present in the DB, but when I search on 'tools' it will not return anything, as tools is not present in the DB.

- word present in DB = 'tool'
- search in DB with word 'tool' = returns results
- search in DB with word 'tools' = returns noting as tools is not present

When I search on the word 'tools' it should also return any results that matches with 'tool'

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'or',
    ['like', 'product.name', $this->searchValue],
    ['like', 'product.desc', $this->searchValue],
]);
```

Comment: ok, probably beacuse your query generate somethin like this SELECT * FROM table WHERE product.name LIKE '%tools%'. You need ['like', 'product.name', '%tools', false] will generate name LIKE '%tools'

Comment: I have tried wildcards, but this will return less results and even no results when I use tools

Comment: Why would you expect that `tools` will match the result containing `tool` or 'tooll', 'toolo'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find similar results and sort by similarity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338889/how-to-find-similar-results-and-sort-by-similarity)

Answer (score 0):

You could run the search string through the `singularize` inflector.

```
$value = yii\helpers\Inflector::singularize($this->searchValue);
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'or',
    ['like', 'product.name', $value],
    ['like', 'product.desc', $value],
]);
```

Obviously this will only work for single word plurals.

Ed.

Comment: Well this will still not return the results

Comment: Yes it will, in your example, if `$this->searchValue` is 'tools' `$value` will be 'tool'.

Comment: Yes thats why I mentioned it would only work for plurals, you will probably need to have a combination of something like soundex and a full-text index on the DB to get near misses.

Answer (score 0):

You can search using below query :

```
$query->andFilterWhere(
 "product.name LIKE CONCAT('%',$this->searchValue,'%') OR
  product.desc LIKE CONCAT('%',$this->searchValue,'%')"
);
```